# Can't change Visual Effects when running Unity

Tags: 10.10, unity, ubuntu-netbook, compiz

I installed ubuntu 10.10 netbook edition on acer aspire one happy. I tried to change the visual effects however it won't let me. It says Mutter is running, can't switch to other effects. I'd like to know how I can switch to other effects. Thank you from now.

Answer (score 1):

The "Visual Effects" configuration is based on Compiz, while the default Unity user interface in Ubuntu 10.10 Netbook Edition uses Mutter.  If you want the regular effects in Ubuntu 10.10, you will have to run the Desktop session (you can select it from the login screen).

In the future Ubuntu 11.04 release (normally released in April next year), the Unity user interface will be based on Compiz, so then you will have "the best of both worlds"...